# How to create a new revision of a task definition in ecs using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

Working on a shell script to create a new revision of a ecs task definition & update the ecs service.

Could you please help me out with the aws cli commands (with example) to achieve the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just call `aws ecs register-task-definition` again, the same command you used to create the initial task definition. A new revision number will be assigned, and returned in the output, each time you call that.

Comment: Thanks, having issues while passing arguments. Could you please share me an example?

Comment: Solved it like this:  filePath="/bin/LEAP/$task_family.json"

export task_version=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://$filePath --region $region | jq --raw-output '.taskDefinition.revision')
echo "Registered ECS Task Definition: " $task_version